# C# Error while opening programmatically generated Excel file from a C# desktop application: "File format or file extension is not valid"

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I am using the following code to generate an Excel .xlsx file from a C# WinForms application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

As of now, the code simply creates a blank Excel file.
When I try to open the xlsx file, I get the following error. **But if I rename the file extension to .xls, the file opens file.**

[image]

```
void WriteData(DataSet ds, string excelFilePath)
{
    Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel = null;
    Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
    Excel.Sheets workSheets = null;
    Excel.Workbook wb = null;
    Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
    Excel.Workbook wbTemplate = null;
    Excel.Range range = null;

    try
    {
        appExcel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        ExcelUtils.InitExcel(appExcel);
        workbooks = appExcel.Workbooks;
        wb = workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        
        wb.SaveAs(excelFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        wb.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    }
    finally
    {
        ExcelUtils.CleanupExcel(appExcel, workbooks, workSheets, wb, ws);
        appExcel = null;
    }
}
```

**I have read other similar questions but most of them are in other languages or using some Excel library.** I need solution using Excel Interop. I do not want to save in OpenXML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `XlFileFormat` member for the format you want when you save the file.

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat):

- `xlWorkbookNormal` is for `*.xls` files.
- `xlWorkbookDefault` is for `*.xlsx` files.

Pass `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault` instead.